# Función plantilla friend de clase plantilla

Tags: c++, c++11, template

Para facilitar el uso de mi clase plantilla, he creado una función auxiliar para que el compilador deduzca los tipos; una práctica común.

La declaración `friend` no provoca ningún error, pero, al intentar llamar a algún método no-público ...

> error: `Test<T>::Test(T) [with T = int]` is private within this context

Parece que mi declaración `friend` **no concuerda** con mi función. Sin embargo, yo lo veo exactamente igual O_O

```
#include <iostream>

template< typename T > class Test {
  template< typename... ARGS > friend Test< T > makeTest( T, ARGS... );

  T m_data;

  Test( T data ) : m_data( std::move( data ) ) { }

public:
  Test( ) : m_data( ) { }

  T data( ) const { return m_data; }
};

template< typename T, typename... ARGS > Test< T > makeTest( T t, ARGS... ) {
  return Test< T >( std::move( t ) );
}

int main( ) {
  Test< int > t = makeTest( 10 );

  std::cout << t.data( ) << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Código de prueba en [<kbd>wandbox</kbd>](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1eva5ZeQJhKgYBvc).

He intentado pre-declarando la función plantilla, con idéntico resultado:

```
template< typename T > class Test;

template< typename T, typename... ARGS > Test< T > makeTest( T t, ARGS... );

template< typename T > class Test {
  template< typename... ARGS > friend Test< T > makeTest( T, ARGS... );
  .
  .
  .
```

> error: `Test<T>::Test(T) [with T = int]` is private within this context

#### EDITO

Creo que no me he sabido explicar adecuadamente; a ver ahora.

A mis ojos, **la instanciación** de

```
template< typename T, typename... ARGS > Test< T > makeTest( T t, ARGS... ) {
  return Test< T >( std::move( t ) );
}
```

**Debería** generar algo así (extremadamente burda aproximación al proceso):

```
Test_int makeTest_int( int t ) {
  return Test_int( t );
}
```

Lo cual **debería de coincidir** con mi declaración `friend` anterior

```
template< typename T > class Test {
  template< typename... ARGS > friend Test< T > makeTest( T, ARGS... );
```

que debería de instanciarse en algó mas o menos así:

```
class Test_int {
  friend Test_int makeTest_int( int );
  ...
```

Eso es lo que no entiendo: Si ambas *instanciaciones* coinciden ...

```
class Test_int {
  friend Test_int makeTest_int( int );
  ...
};

Test_int makeTest_int( int t ) {
  return Test_int( t );
}
```

¿ Porqué el compilador dice que **no es lo mismo** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿ porqué el compilador dice que no es lo mismo ?

Para identificar las diferentes funciones, el compilador utiliza una suerte de nombres simbólicos. Estos nombres se generan a partir de la **declaración** de las diferentes clases y funciones.

Teniendo esto en cuenta es facil ver que estas declaraciones no van a generar el mismo nombre simbólico:

```
template< typename T > class Test {
  template< typename... ARGS > friend Test< T > makeTest( T, ARGS... );

template< typename T, typename... ARGS > friend Test< T > makeTest( T, ARGS... );
```

En el primer caso, `makeTest` solo define **un único tipo**, `ARGS`, mientras que el segundo define **dos**, `T` y `ARGS`. Que `ARGS` sea varíadico y ambas funciones puedan ser equivalentes a la hora de ser invocadas es irrelevante aquí. Lo importante es que su declaración **no es la misma**, ya que una declara **dos tipos** mientras que la otra solo declara **uno**.

Answer (score 2):

La función amiga no es la misma que la función libre:

`Amiga`

```
template< typename... ARGS > friend Test< T > makeTest( T, ARGS... )
```

`Libre`

```
template< typename T, typename... ARGS > Test< T > makeTest( T t, ARGS... )
```

Por lo tanto, crees que hay amistad entre la función libre y el objeto `Test` pero en realidad le has dado derechos de amistad a otra función, esto debería corregir el problema:

```
template< typename T > class Test {
  template< typename A, typename... ARGS > friend Test< A > makeTest( A, ARGS... );

  T m_data;

  Test( T data ) : m_data( std::move( data ) ) { }

public:
  Test( ) : m_data( ) { }

  T data( ) const { return m_data; }
};
```

> Al usar el mismo parámetro de plantilla `T` tanto en la clase plantilla como en la declaración `friend`, yo esperaba que el compilador dedujera `el mismo tipo en ambas partes`. Veo que ¿ esto no es así entonces ?

No se puede deducir lo que no se ha pedido ser deducido. El parámetro de plantilla `T` pertenece a la clase, no a la función `makeTest`. Es más, la función `makeTest` está en el espacio global de nombres y es un símbolo completamente independiente del objeto `Test`, al fin y al cabo puedes llamar a `makeTest` sin disponer de una instancia de `Test` por lo tanto ¿Cómo se supone que tiene que deducir algo que ni siquiera conoce?

En resumen, puedes usar las plantillas en múltiples contextos:

- Objetos plantilla.
- Funciones plantilla.
- Objetos no plantilla con funciones plantilla.
- Objetos plantilla con funciones plantilla.

Y en cada uno de esos contextos, cada una de esas plantillas será diferente e independiente, tanto es así que incluso puedes tener conflictos en los nombres:

```
template <typename T>
struct Plantilla
{
    /* Error! El parámetro de la función plantilla oculta el parámetro
       de la clase plantilla! */
    template <typename T>
    void funcion(T){}
};
```

Comment: Al usar el mismo parámetro de plantilla `T` tanto en la clase plantilla como en la declaración `friend`, yo *esperaba* que el compilador dedujera `el mismo tipo en ambas partes`. Veo que ¿ esto no es así entonces ?